# Testcontainers kill process by bash (jvm)

Tags: java, bash, jvm, testcontainers

I have test with my app in container that running in `testcontainers`. My test should check graceful shutdown of app and i need to kill main process with TERM signal. I can't use

> dockerClient.killContainerCmd()

because our test env has zero timeout for TERM signals. So i want to call `kill -15 1` in container for similar behavior. But when i use

> container.execInContainer("kill -15 1")

or

> container.dockerClient.execCreateCmd(container.containerId).withCmd("kill -9 1")

i got smt like `executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`.
I can do `docker exec -it **** /bin/bash` and call `kill -15 1` in container - thats work correctly. Is any ability or hack to call `kill` by `testcontainers` api ?

Comment: `execinContainer()` may be a literal `exec()` and not invoke a shell for `$PATH` expansion. Try using the absolute path to `kill`.

Comment: @Sammitch thank you. But i try to find `kill` with `type -a kill` and in container it is shell builtin app. I try smt like '/usr/bin/bash -c 'kill -15 1'' but it return `stat /usr/bin/bash -c 'kill -15 1': no such file or directory: unknown`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was in args. I try use

```
container.execInContainer("bash -c 'kill -15 1'") //invalid
```

But work solution is

```
container.execInContainer("bash", "-c", "kill -15 1")
```

If your env used kuber-api for tests and you have testcontainers in your project - kuber-api doesn`t allow to kill 1 pid. so you can do next hack:

```
container.withCreateContainerCmdModifier { cmd => 
      cmd.withEntrypoint(
        "bash",
        "-c",
        s"echo $$BASHPID >/tmp/pid; exec ${YOUR_RUN_CMD}"
      )
}
...
container.execInContainer("bash", "-c", "kill -15 $(cat /tmp/pid)")
```